# Google Analytics DataChart - how to display month index as month name?

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization

I have a an analytics DataChart which displays monthly traffic. The problem is, the x-axis is showing month indices and I want it to show month name labels (e.g. January, February, March, etc.). Is there a way I can format the month axis as the month name?

```js
  var pastYearChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'ids': my_ID,
      'start-date': '365daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:users',
      'dimensions': 'ga:month'
    },
    chart: {
      'container': 'traffic-past-year-container',
      'type': 'COLUMN',
      'options': {
        'width': '100%'
      }
    }
  });
```

[image: data chart]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding 'hAxis': {'format': 'MMMM'}, but it doesn't seem to change the format of the horizontal axis (which I'm using ga:month to get).

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "etc"
];

for(var i = 0, len = month.length; i < len; i++) {
    // month[i] contains your month based on your index
}
```

Comment: Sure, I know that part, but how do I plug it into the chart? :)